# My separate method keeps returning the wrong value

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, return-value

I'm using my weight as a value of 180 to find my weight in lbs on planets other than earth with a formula to find weight using mass and surface gravity. The problem I'm facing is that whenever I call this method, the weight value returns as 180 all 8 times the method is called. In my code I have weight being calculated with (mass * roundedSG)/433... It shouldn't return as 180. I don't know how to fix this, I've been trying for a couple hours. The for loop is in a different method, I'm doing this for home work by the way, any help would be appreciated to just try and fix this problem of mine. Thanks!

```
public static double weight(double sGravity, double w) 
{
    double roundedSG = sGravity / 10;
    double mass = (w * 433.59237)/roundedSG;
    double weight = (mass * roundedSG)/433.59237;

    return weight;
}

    for(int i = 0; i < planetSurfaceGravity.length; i++)
    {
        weightOnPlanets[i] = weight(planetSurfaceGravity[i], weightLbs);
        System.out.println(weightOnPlanets[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the for loop belong to another method?

Comment: Yep, it's in the main method.

Comment: Where is the main method? Post the methods relevant to your  expected result.

Comment: Your 'weight' method is returning different results depending on the incoming parameters. it's gotta be in your caller. So your planetSurfaceGravity[i] probably does not change.
On a site note, I would change the method name to something like "calculateWeight". Better be some action or verb.

Comment: I posted the main method.

Comment: Maybe 'weight' is returning the same results regardless of the incoming parameters! See my answer for details.

Comment: Where is readSGravity()  ?

Comment: I don't think readSGravity has any errors, it returns the text file's information just fine, I posted it nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed your variables and added a constant which makes the code as written a bit clearer:

```
private static final double GRAMS_PER_POUND = 433.59237;
public static double weight(double sGravity, double weightLbs)  
{
    double roundedSG = sGravity / 10;
    double mass = (weightLbs * GRAMS_PER_POUND)/roundedSG;
    double weight = (mass * roundedSG)/GRAMS_PER_POUND;

    return weight;
}
```

So your mass on earth, which is converted to grams, is being divided by the gravity of whatever planet you're checking. Change the mass calculation to be

```
double mass = weightLbs * GRAMS_PER_POUND;
```

Then the weight calculation should be ok as is, returning the weight on the other planet converted back from grams to pounds.

Comment: without knowing the contents of gravity1.txt I have no idea if dividing sGravity by 10 is the right thing to do. I wouldn't round at that point. I'd prefer to either return the value as an unrounded double and let the caller do the rounding, or round the final calculation of weight.

Comment: Your answer was correct, I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong until I just read your answer.  I was dividing it by 10 as the homework assignment wanted me to since they said it brings it closer to the formula they'd like us to use. I figured it'd be fine to do it in that method, but I'll take your advice into count. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

I think your math in weight() is incorrect. It looks like weight is actually returning the following:

```
 (w * 433/roundedSG)*roundedSG/433.
```

The 433s and roundedSGs cancel, and you're just returning w, which I'm guessing is 180?

Comment: I'm returning weight, not w I believe. The mass value should be 80460.439793814432989690721649485 if it were earth's SG that I'm using in the array. This multiplied by earth's SG again should be 78046.6266 / 433. I think this is what I'm trying to do, and what I thought I did.

Comment: Write out the final calculation, weight=mass*roundedSG/433. Then expand mass to mass=(w*433)/roundedSG. It looks to me like everything but the 'w' gets canceled.

Comment: mass = (weight) * (433.59237) / (surface gravity) and from there I would simply do weight = mass * surfaceG... I don't know how to make it so that it doesn't cancel out then? This should be the step according to the formula they gave us. I'm sorry if I don't understand, haha.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the goal correctly. You'd like to take your weight on Earth, and then apply the formula to find your weight on other planets. In this case, You'd want to do something like:

mass = weightOnEarth / gravityOnEarth,
massOnPlanetX = mass * gravityOnPlanetX

I think your issue is that you're using the gravityOnEarth in both situations, although I'm not totally sure where the 433.... comes from.

Comment: Well, what the formula and homework wants me to do is get the weight in grams, which it is initially as that's what you use in the formula. If I take away the  double weight = (mass * roundedSG)/433.59237; 433 in this, I get the weight in grams, however, it shows the same value over and over(e.g. 78k) 8 times as that's how many times it's called. I know it's not using the same surface gravity to calculate it as I tried returning roundedSG instead of weight and it returns all 8 different SG values. Shouldn't it return at least 8 different values because of this?

Comment: This is miserably difficult to do in comments without formatting. I think pdmoore might have the right idea in their answer.

Comment: He did, I can only say thanks to you as well since you took the time to try and help me understand what you were saying. Perdomoff was also correct. I just didn't get what you guys wanted until now, I wish I could put you three as all the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Weight Formula is:

> weight = (mass*gravity);

Change from:

```
 double weight = (mass * roundedSG)/433.59237;
```

To:

```
double weight = mass * roundedSG;
```

Comment: When I do that it's returning the weight, 78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
78046.6266
, in grams rather than in lbs like I need it to, also, it returns the same number over and over when I have different values for the surface gravity. If I call for the surface gravity I get, 0.37
0.8869999999999999
0.9789999999999999
0.371
2.48
1.043
0.8869999999999999
1.114
which are all the numbers I'm supposed to get. I don't understand why it keeps repeating the same weight value over and over yet it shows the different surface gravity values. Thanks.

Comment: Yes there are other things going on, but your weight formula is wrong. What is in that  gravity1.txt ?

Comment: 3.70
8.87
9.79
3.71
24.80
10.43
8.87
11.14
These are the numbers in the gravity1.txt file. In the weight method above I divided it by 10 to get the numbers they wanted.

Comment: @Alexcz, is that in pounds or grams??

Comment: They were the surface gravity of the planets I had to calculate, I understand what you wanted me to do now, you were correct, I just didn't get it until now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You weight method calculation are incorrect. the result of it returns only w which you pass as weightLbs (= 180).